# Is it possible to buy a replacement iPad screen of the same quality as Apple's?

Tags: ipad, repair, digitizer

I've found a few companies that offer replacement iPad digitizers (the digitizer is the glass/touch screen part of your iPad), but I'm worried that they might be different to the official one.

[image]

Having [broken the glass on my iPad 3](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71804/cracked-ipad-display-what-are-my-options) I initially spoke to Apple, but they wanted far too much to repair it ($400!). I then looked into third-party repairs (which were still quite pricey), and then discovered DIY repair kits.

Replacing the glass doesn't seem too difficult, [based on the tutorials I've looked at](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=95H9d5O67R8), so my only concern now is the quality of the replacement kits.

Is it possible to buy a repair kit that has parts that are (more or less) identical to Apple's? I wouldn't want to replace the a part with something inferior :(

Comment: Where are you buying from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[iFixit](http://www.ifixit.com/Device/iPad) is a great resource for repair manuals and the corresponding parts.  It appears they currently (2-13) have [iPad digitizers](http://www.ifixit.com/iPad-Parts) for ~$100.

Personally I only have experience purchasing internal iPhone parts from them, but they are a reputable company and I would trust their quality if I were in your position.

Comment: Wow, that's quite a bit more expensive than other Digitizers I've seen -- I guess it's because it's exactly the same as Apple's(?). It might be me just paying a third-party company at that rate. (They have kit with the home button installed and all the adhesives in place, but including shipping to the UK, that's $175!)

Comment: What is your target price range?

Comment: I just want to get my iPad back to being as good as new for as cheap as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Through my personal experience I recommend you [iPad 3 Screen Repair Guide](http://ipadscreenrepair.com/ipad-3-screen-repair-guide/). I like ifixit's stuff, but they always fall short. They just tell you to put it back together the way you took it apart. After successfully following this guide I can tell you that you definitely need to know the special tips to put it back together correctly. “iPad 3 Screen Repair Guide” they have a video as well as a step by step guide. I hope this helps you out!